# GAE Simple Request Handler only run once

Tags: python, google-app-engine, request, handler

Good day!

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/helloworld
this is the hello world that I'm trying to run.

I can seeing the

```
Hello, world!
Status: 500
```

message. however it will be turned to a "HTTP Error 500" after I hit the refresh.
and... it seems that the appengine only shows me the good result once after I re-save either app.yaml or helloworld.py

This is the trace for the good result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'helloworld' from 'D:\work\[GAE] tests\helloworld\helloworld.pyc'> has no attribute app
INFO     2012-06-23 01:47:28,522 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ERROR    2012-06-23 01:47:30,040 wsgi.py:189]
```

and this is the trace for the Error 500

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'helloworld' from 'D:\work\[GAE] tests\helloworld\helloworld.pyc'> has no attribute app
INFO     2012-06-23 01:47:30,127 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

here's my helloworld.py

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

my main.py. (app is used instead of application)

```
import webapp2

class hello(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('normal hello')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', hello),
], debug = True)
```

and the app.yaml

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /hello
  script: helloworld.app

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
```

any clue what's causing this?

Regards,

Comment: you are using python27: see the related [getting started](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't creating a `helloworld.app` object in your helloworld.py module.

See the lines

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplications([...
```

in your main.py file? That creates the main.app object that's referenced by the `script: main.app` handler in your app.yaml.

You're referencing a `helloworld.app` object a couple of lines above; that object doesn't exist. Python 2.7 in App Engine doesn't support the simple module model -- no WSGI handler, just a simple script -- that's used in the 2.5 "Hello World" demo.

As presveva said, use the 2.7 Getting Started guide for less confusion.

Comment: thanks!!!!! finally solved the mystery!
together, the googleAPI + oauth2 problem is solved too!!
previously I thought that the *.app as 2.7 == *.py as 2.5 XD lol